# Вызов функции одного класса внутри функции другого класса

Tags: c++

Как передать функцию, возвращающую некоторую величину из одного класса в качестве переменной в функции, определенной в другом классе. На данный момент мой код выглядит примерно так:

```
float A::decay(){
    B b;
    float N;
    const int HL=946; 
    const int G=126;
    float T;
    if(b.min()>0){
        T=(float)(b.min()-G)/HL;
        N=pow(2,-T);
    }
    return N;
}

int B::min(){
    int min=dtim[0][0][0];
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){    
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++){
            for(int q=0; q<L; q++){
                if (dtime[i][j][q] < min)min = dtime[i][j][q];
            }
        }
    }
    return min;
}
```

При попытке вызова функции min() в decay(), min всегда равен нулю.

Comment: вам известно что такое указатель на функию ?

Comment: @ampawd не отказался бы от объяснения на примере данного кода

Answer (score 1):

У вас проблема скорее в вычислении `min`, а не в передаче функции. Вернее, не в **передаче**, а **вызове**. Вы не делаете ничего сверхъестественного... Код ниже - упрощенная версия вашего. Но что такое у вас `dtim`, какие там значения и т.д. и т.п. - этого же мы не знаем! Потом, у вас в `decay` создается объект `B` конструктором по умолчанию - так и надо? Может, в этом `b` все элементы `dtim` - нулевые?

Другое дело, если вам действительно надо передать функцию-член одного класса в другую...

```
class B
{
public:
    B(int x):x(x){}

    void out()
    {
        cout << "b = " << x << endl;
    }
private:
    int x;
};


class A
{
public:
    void func(int x)
    {
        B b(x);
        b.out();
    }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    A a;
    a.func(5);
}
```

Comment: второй вариант, вычисляемые значения min верны, при вызове печати из класса B

Comment: @robado Знаете, приведите все же какой-то минимальный самодостаточный пример - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1):

По указателю, очевидно.

Но проще передать указатель на класс, и уже оттуда вызвать нужный метод.

```
float A::decay(B * b){
// B b; - это больше не нужно
... здесь без изменений
if (b->min()>0){
....
```